# Teradata QVCI Feature Disabled

Tags: r, teradata, rodbc

I am trying to utilize the `RODBC::sqlSAVE()` function in R, but I am getting an error that `HY000 -9719 [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] QVCI feature is disabled.` which is throwing an error. How can I enable QVCI in Teradata? I am using ODBC to connect, version 16.20 on Windows via ODBC Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a very early version of Teradata 16.20 client driver. Upgrade to current patch level of Teradata ODBC, or consider switching to [Teradata SQL Driver for R](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/teradata-sql-driver-for-r).